# Rotating hatch labels based on orientation changes in Data Driven Pages Strip maps?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling, data-driven-pages, strip-map

I've created a strip map for a linear feature and have it loaded as a data driven page.  I want to show stationing for the line.  The stationing displays properly on the first data driven page but on each subsequent page the stationing labels get messed up as the map orientation changes. I want the stationing labels perpendicular to the linear feature as shown in the first image.  The tick marks seem to rotate and stay perpendicular to the line but the labels won't.

How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Anyone?  Surely I can't be the only one dealing with this issue?

Comment: Are your labels annotations or live labels?

Answer (score 2):

I have run into the same problem. The issue comes in as you move through your DDP sheets, a new angle (which aligns with your alignment) is entered into your Data Frame. This for some reason messes up the labeling orientation.

How I have worked around this to is set your data frame angle to 0°. Get your labels how you like them (perpendicular to the line) and then export them to graphics.  Once they are graphics then rotating your data frame will not impact their orientation.

Comment: Thank you Seamster02.  This does work and is acceptable but it can be frustrating if for some reason I need to turn them on and off.  Can't help but thing there is a more traditional way of doing it with annotation but this should work for now.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I also have encountered this problem. I do things slightly different though. Instead of using hatches, I make a route event layer and check the Generate an angle field option. This creates a LOC_ANGLE field that you can use when setting up the symbology for the point. The symbol will rotate perpendicular to the line as you go through your data driven pages. HOWEVER, when labeling the symbol, the LOC_ANGLE doesn't work the same. I like to have the labels perpendicular to the symbol, rotated 90 degrees, reading bottom to top. I can't get that to happen. My fix as been to just rotate the label 90 degrees period. It doesn't look as nice, and sometimes covers the line, but I can't come up with anything better. And, you don't have to worry about annotating the labels.

Hopefully that will help someone.